# How to reuse a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter I want a particular widget to be reused with different images at run time.

How to attain this is giving me difficulties I would like to know how to get this.

I am writing the peice of code kindly suggest what is a correct way

```
       scaffold: CupertinoPageScaffold(
         navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          trailing: Image.asset('assets/Menu_Button.png'),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Material(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                       new Stack(children: <Widget>[
                       new Container(
                          child: background.Row1
                       ),
                      Container(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/card_bg.png')
                      ),
                    ]
                    ),

                    Container(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                     child: Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                     children: <Widget>[
                     ShowingOptions('assets/image1.png').Options,//*****calling function with parameter so that it can put widget**********//
                     ShowingOptions('assets/image2.png').Options,
                     ShowingOptions('assets/image3.png').Options,
                     ShowingOptions('assets/image4.png').Options,


              ],
              ),

                  background.Row2,
                  background.Row3
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ))
            ),
      );
      }
     }

     /**********function defination starts *************/
    ShowingOptions(image) {

     Widget Options =  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 7, 
              right: 7, top: 5),
         child: Container(
         height: 55.0,
          width: 55.0,

            child: Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
               child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

                radius: 10,
                  child: new Image.asset(image, height: 150, width: 
               150),
              )),
             decoration: new BoxDecoration(
           shape: BoxShape.circle,
           color: Colors.white,
           border: new Border.all(
             color: Colors.orange,
            width: 5.0,
           ),
        )
        ),  

    );
  }
     }
               /**********function defination ends *************/
```

What Iam doing is making a funciton and when I am calling the function 'showOptions('assets/image1')' I am passing the image that I need to show.

Inside the function defination I am writing a widget that I wanted to be placed whenevr I call that funcition bys showing the image that I have passed

the way I implemented this whole is not working want a solution. I know this is not the proper way as I am new I would like to have some guidance.

Comment: is your goal to show the images, using that Widget/function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Custom Widget,

1. Create a Stateless or Stateful Class
2. declare Required Vairables
3. return your Custom Widget

below is Example of CustomButton with onPressed event.

```
  //Create a Stateless or Stateful Class
  class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {

  //declare Required Vairables
  final String buttonText;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final bool loading;

  //constructor 
  CustomButton({this.buttonText,this.onPressed,this.loading});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30,right: 30),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
              color: Colors.red),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                  splashColor: Colors.green,
                  onTap: onPressed,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Center(child:
                    loading==true?
                        CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white,)
                        :
                    Text(buttonText,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,color: Colors.white),)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


}
```

Use :

```
CustomButtonSmall(buttonText: "Direction",onPressed: (){})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://itnext.io/reusable-widgets-reusable-custom-appbars-in-flutter-4d4b8b06d176) is a wonderfully explained example of how to achieve this easily.

I just copy the code from there. You basically have to create a separate class for the widget you have in mind:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  AppTextFormField({
    this.controller,
    this.hintText,
    this.helpText,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIcon,
    this.isPassword,
    this.enabled,
    this.readOnly,
    this.borderColor,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final String helpText;
  final IconData prefixIcon;
  final IconData suffixIcon;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool enabled;
  final bool readOnly;
  final Color borderColor;@override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        readOnly: null == readOnly ? false : true,
        obscureText: null == isPassword ? false : true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: null == borderColor ? Colors.teal : borderColor,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: null == hintText ? '' : hintText,
          helperText: null == helpText ? '' : helpText,
          prefixIcon: null == prefixIcon ? null : Icon(prefixIcon),
          suffix: null == suffixIcon ? null : Icon(suffixIcon),
          enabled: null == enabled ? true : false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then in the class where you want to use the widget you call the it like this:

```
Container(
    child: Column(
        children: [
        AppTextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            helpText: 'Email',
            hintText: 'Email',
            prefixIcon: Icons.email,
        ),
        AppTextFormField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            helpText: 'Password',
            hintText: 'Password',
            isPassword: true,
            prefixIcon: Icons.lock_open,
        ),
```

You don't have to use all the methods, just the ones you need.